# Batch cropping WMF

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, image-editing, vector-graphics, wmf

I have lots of wmf images from a simulation software which need to be included in a word document. To maintain best quality wmf seems to be the only way. The software creates a frame around the plot but due to a known bug does this only on two sides - so the partial frame has to be removed.

To my understanding wmf as a vector graphic can't be actually cropped. If you know a way to do that let me know ;-)

In Word you can crop the images which works for me. The annoyance is that this can only be done by mouse and for a single image so it takes a lot of time and doesn't always "cut" away the same amount. All images have the same size/aspect ratio and should be cropped equally.

Is there any way to automate this or at least define the amount of cropping exactly (not with mouse)?

Comment: Are you ok with the output no longer being strictly vector? I.e. does the cropping software only need to be able to read wmfs, but you can use say png?

Comment: Output has to remain a vector but my problem has been resolved in the meantime since the simulation software now creates proper output files.